# D3.js rendered page crashes on all major browsers on Mac but doesn't crash on Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: macos, safari, d3.js

I have an eleborate web page built with d3.js, with lots of elements, animation and event-listeners. And it crashes on Mac (both Safari and Chrome) when I start actively using it. Works fine under Windows and Ubuntu though.

Here's head of crash report (Safari) (I can provide full stack if needed):

```
Process:         WebProcess [3371]
Path:            /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcess
Identifier:      com.apple.WebProcess
Version:         8536 (8536.30.1)
Build Info:      WebKit2-7536030001000000~9
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  ??? [3368]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-07-22 06:23:37.723 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          44964 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  36105 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      B207ABFE-2713-74A6-B3B1-725AF872DA13

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000028

VM Regions Near 0x28:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010212e000-000000010212f000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcess

Application Specific Information:
Bundle controller class:
BrowserBundleController
```

What might be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like a webkit bug to me. Did you try with a browser with a different layout engine (e.g. firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Here's more of the crash report** 

    Process:         WebProcess [239]
Path:            /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcess
Identifier:      com.apple.WebProcess
Version:         8536 (8536.30.1)
Build Info:      WebKit2-7536030001000000~9
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  ??? [237]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-07-23 09:47:09.948 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          15004 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           5
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  3920 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      B207ABFE-2713-74A6-B3B1-725AF872DA13

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000028

VM Regions Near 0x28:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000102017000-0000000102018000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcess

Application Specific Information:
Bundle controller class:
BrowserBundleController


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c555f14 WebCore::textDistance(WebCore::Position const&, WebCore::Position const&) + 20
1   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c38c1a7 WebCore::EventHandler::handleMousePressEventSingleClick(WebCore::MouseEventWithHitTestResults const&) + 919
2   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c38ba70 WebCore::EventHandler::handleMousePressEvent(WebCore::MouseEventWithHitTestResults const&) + 752
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c38b690 WebCore::EventHandler::handleMousePressEvent(WebCore::PlatformMouseEvent const&) + 2384
4   com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d37e062 WebKit::handleMouseEvent(WebKit::WebMouseEvent const&, WebKit::WebPage*, bool) + 165
5   com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d37df8f WebKit::WebPage::mouseEvent(WebKit::WebMouseEvent const&) + 127
6   com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d38a287 void CoreIPC::handleMessage<Messages::WebPage::MouseEvent, WebKit::WebPage, void (WebKit::WebPage::*)(WebKit::WebMouseEvent const&)>(CoreIPC::ArgumentDecoder*, WebKit::WebPage*, void (WebKit::WebPage::*)(WebKit::WebMouseEvent const&)) + 83
7   com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d351ef1 WebKit::WebConnectionToUIProcess::didReceiveMessage(CoreIPC::Connection*, CoreIPC::MessageID, CoreIPC::ArgumentDecoder*) + 179
8   com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d2bca1d CoreIPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(CoreIPC::Connection::Message<CoreIPC::ArgumentDecoder>&) + 175
9   com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d2ffbd5 CoreIPC::Connection::dispatchOneMessage() + 139
10  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8ccd6a8c WebCore::RunLoop::performWork() + 156
11  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8ccd7127 WebCore::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 71
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9668bb31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9668b455 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966ae7f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966ae0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93b06eb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93b06c52 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93b06ae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9074c533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9074bdf2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff907431a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
22  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8ccd74ff WebCore::RunLoop::run() + 63
23  com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d3ac462 WebKit::WebProcessMain(WebKit::CommandLine const&) + 2586
24  com.apple.WebKit2               0x00007fff8d372bfd WebKitMain + 285
25  com.apple.WebProcess            0x0000000102017e7b 0x102017000 + 3707
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8ff707e1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fbad16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9427adea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9427a9ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5e1fe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff9188eb66 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 118
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ab1bfa JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 90
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ac725f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5e1fe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91a149d4 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 212
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91a148b6 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ac725f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5e1fe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91a149d4 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 212
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91a148b6 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ac725f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5e1fe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91a149d4 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 212
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91a148b6 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ac725f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fb8686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fb7c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966a9233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966ae916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966ae0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8da00546 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 356
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8da5e562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: WebCore: Scrolling
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fb8686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fb7c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966a9233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966ae916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966ae0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966bcdd1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8ccec5e1 WebCore::ScrollingThread::initializeRunLoop() + 273
7   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ac725f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba322 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff966edf46 __CFSocketManager + 1302
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:: WebCore: LocalStorage
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5e1fe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff9188eb2d WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 61
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8cd11d01 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::StorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::StorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WebCore::StorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::StorageTask*), double) + 81
4   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c26212a WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 154
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ac725f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: WebCore: LocalStorage
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5e1fe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff9188eb2d WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 61
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8cd11d01 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::StorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::StorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WebCore::StorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::StorageTask*), double) + 81
4   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c26212a WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 154
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff91ac725f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dff4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dfd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dff4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dfd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dff4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dfd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5e2023 _pthread_cond_wait + 927
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8dea0ea3 CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 271
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8dea0201 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 529
4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8de9ffd7 startIOThread(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dd7a2 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dff4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dfd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dff4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dfd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94fba6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dff4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5dfd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d5ca1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff5dbe6cc0  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007fff5dbe6d30  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007fff5dbe6d30  rsi: 0x00007fff5dbe6cc0  rbp: 0x00007fff5dbe6bb0  rsp: 0x00007fff5dbe6b90
   r8: 0x000000012e1aac00   r9: 0x000000000000003f  r10: 0x000000011453ebc0  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x00000001495a3000  r13: 0x00007fff5dbe6f68  r14: 0x0000000106304aa8  r15: 0x00007fff5dbe6d30
  rip: 0x00007fff8c555f14  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000028
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
       0x102017000 -        0x102017fff  com.apple.WebProcess (8536 - 8536.30.1) <F967F09F-969C-3788-9376-7B4067F402B4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcess
       0x102021000 -        0x102021fff  WebProcessShim.dylib (7536.30.1) <15AC7990-1B63-3AD9-905F-7331C901A578> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcessShim.dylib
       0x104ff3000 -        0x105009fff  com.apple.WebInspector (8536 - 8536.30) <7DD903D1-505E-34D3-835A-15BE44CC49B6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebInspector.framework/Versions/A/WebInspector
       0x106f37000 -        0x1070a7fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib (8.9.2) <83DBCC22-F711-3F9D-B622-6DE5D9DD90AE> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
       0x1070df000 -        0x1070ecfff  libGPUSupport.dylib (8.9.2) <0D32763C-7F3D-3FDB-9EDB-760BB7AFFA04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGPUSupport.dylib
       0x1070f3000 -        0x1070f8fff  com.apple.IOAccelerator (74.5.1 - 74.5.1) <574EC60B-E292-3FEA-8A66-B12DB2C1CEC5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/Versions/A/IOAccelerator
       0x107102000 -        0x1072c0fff  GLEngine (8.9.2) <420E03C3-B91D-33C7-A1C4-BE60A1544971> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
       0x1072f7000 -        0x107303fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib (8.9.2) <971EDFC6-3E6A-375C-9133-F50DFDDCEBDD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
       0x10770a000 -        0x107735fff  GLRendererFloat (8.9.2) <18D6F0AD-C5F1-3E8F-89C2-89426A3D6FE4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat
       0x10773e000 -        0x107747fe7  libcldcpuengine.dylib (2.2.16) <DB9678F6-7D50-384A-A961-6109B61D1607> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libcldcpuengine.dylib
       0x1077a3000 -        0x107c2bff7  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver (8.12.47 - 8.1.2) <ED3787B7-1558-3C4C-8F84-7E810A27FF7E> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver
       0x1087a6000 -        0x1087bcff7  com.apple.webcontentfilter.framework (3.1 - 5) <E18D99F4-A52C-30C8-9D70-D0E34DB9D68C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebContentAnalysis.framework/WebContentAnalysis
       0x1090ce000 -        0x1090cfff7  ATSHI.dylib (341.1) <3328D0EC-BD75-3041-A458-05FFE934C019> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ATSHI.dylib
       0x10e4f4000 -        0x10e51afff  libPDFRIP.A.dylib (332) <22085533-A0BE-3660-9312-7BC9E2A69576> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPDFRIP.A.dylib
       0x200000000 -        0x20092eff7  com.apple.GeForceGLDriver (8.12.47 - 8.1.2) <C54C54E7-855D-3C7C-84A0-C20F082E32E9> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceGLDriver
    0x7fff61c17000 -     0x7fff61c4b93f  dyld (210.2.3) <A40597AA-5529-3337-8C09-D8A014EB1578> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8bf47000 -     0x7fff8bfe5ff7  com.apple.ink.framework (10.8.2 - 150) <84B9825C-3822-375F-BE58-A753444FBDE2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff8bfe6000 -     0x7fff8c144fef  com.apple.MediaControlSender (1.7 - 170.20) <853BE89D-49B0-3922-9ED5-DDBDE9A97356> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/Versions/A/MediaControlSender
    0x7fff8c145000 -     0x7fff8c242fff  libsqlite3.dylib (138.1) <ADE9CB98-D77D-300C-A32A-556B7440769F> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff8c243000 -     0x7fff8d202ff7  com.apple.WebCore (8536 - 8536.30.2) <3FF4783B-EF75-34F5-995C-316557148A18> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
    0x7fff8d203000 -     0x7fff8d284fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 707.11) <2DD25313-420D-351A-90F1-300E95C970CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff8d285000 -     0x7fff8d290ff7  com.apple.ProtocolBuffer (2 - 104) <3270C172-1437-3080-9E53-3E2DCA9AE2EC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/Versions/A/ProtocolBuffer
    0x7fff8d299000 -     0x7fff8d299fff  com.apple.CoreServices (57 - 57) <9DD44CB0-C644-35C3-8F57-0B41B3EC147D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8d29a000 -     0x7fff8d2a7fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib (29) <CE9785E8-B535-3504-B392-82F0064D9AF2> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff8d2a8000 -     0x7fff8d494ff7  com.apple.WebKit2 (8536 - 8536.30.1) <5A3C2412-FF47-3160-9634-32222C98D887> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/WebKit2
    0x7fff8d5a9000 -     0x7fff8d5c0fff  libGL.dylib (8.9.2) <B8E5948D-BCF2-3727-B74E-
```

Comment: I did more testing and it appears to work on Firefox so that suggests this is a Webkit error